# Is projectile motion a free fall motion? Is the vice versa also true?

Tags: projectile, free-fall

We know that in ideal case a projectile will be acted upon by only the gravitational force and hence can it be considered a free fall motion?
An object dropped from a height will be under free fall and can the motion be considered as a case of projectile motion where the object is dropped with a 0 velocity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of free fall is that an object is undergoing downward acceleration under the influence of only gravitational force.  Hence, projectile motion can be considered as free fall as it is falling due to gravity alone.  We can say the converse is true but with 0 *horizontal* velocity.

Comment: Is it your opinion or are you sure that it is true, and if you are could you give me a reference

Comment: Sorry @sammygerbil , I meant acceleration.